# Predefined way to convert generic NSStrings to NSDates

Tags: ios, date, nsstring, nsdateformatter

I'm looking to have a way for user-inputted "date text" (e.g. 3/3/1990 or 3-1-98) to be formatted as an NSDate.

I could implement it myself attempting to format the text with various date formatters but I have a sneaking suspicion that there is a much easier way to do this.

[dateWithNaturalLanguageString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/dateWithNaturalLanguageString:) would probably work, but I hear rumor that this will cause rejection from the app store?

Comment: I bet that gets tricky with locales, which is why apple discourages its use. Does 3-1-98 mean March 1st, 1998 or January 3rd, 1998, etc.

Comment: well ideally there would be some kind of intelligent "locale detector" and two versions of the formatter

Comment: It'd certainly be nifty if someone's built an OS library that hooks into `NSLocale`.

Comment: Mail's data detectors have a decent implementation but sometimes it royally screws up.

Comment: @bummi did as you requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `NSDataDetector` and it returns `NSTextCheckingResult` objects.

Comment: Wicked... I always forget we have access to `NSDataDetector`.

Comment: Oh wow, badass. This is what I'm looking for. I did already just brute force the problem though this is a great thing to know :)

Comment: If you want to see my brute force implementation using this class, scroll down a bit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this covers all of what you need, but the `NSDateFormatter` class has a `dateFromString:` method. If you can recognize what kind of format the string is in and create a corresponding `NSDateFormatter` object, this will do the trick.

Comment: yes, I was simply hoping that there would be some kind of class already written that will just recognize the format of the date and make it work so that the user can input 3-1-10 OR 03/01/2010 and have either entry create the same NSDate object

Comment: I would not rule out NSDateFormatter completely. NSDataDetector is very good, but you may want to format the result after you find it. NSFormatters are some of the classic amazing Foundation classes, and NSDataDetector is a product of the Apple Modern Languages folks who also do pretty incredible work.

Answer (score 0):

So NSDataDetector is my cup o' tea, I did brute force the problem with some introspective if-else statements in a class method. In case anyone in future land is interested:

```
#import "TotalStringToDateFormatter.h"

@implementation TotalStringToDateFormatter

+(NSDate*) convertString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    NSDate* date;
    NSString* checkString;


    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm/dd/yyyy"];
    date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
    checkString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    if ([string isEqualToString:checkString]) {
        return date;
    }

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm-dd-yyyy"];
    date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
    checkString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    if ([string isEqualToString:checkString]) {
        return date;
    }
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"m/d/yyyy"];
    date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
    checkString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    if ([string isEqualToString:checkString]) {
        return date;
    }

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"m-d-yyyy"];
    date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
    checkString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    if ([string isEqualToString:checkString]) {
        return date;
    }
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"m/d/yy"];
    date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
    checkString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    if ([string isEqualToString:checkString]) {
        return date;
    }

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"m-d-yy"];
    date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
    checkString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    if ([string isEqualToString:checkString]) {
        return date;
    }
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm/d/yyyy"];
    date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
    checkString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    if ([string isEqualToString:checkString]) {
        return date;
    }

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm-d-yyyy"];
    date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
    checkString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    if ([string isEqualToString:checkString]) {
        return date;
    }
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"m/dd/yyyy"];
    date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
    checkString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    if ([string isEqualToString:checkString]) {
        return date;
    }

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"m-dd-yyyy"];
    date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
    checkString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    if ([string isEqualToString:checkString]) {
        return date;
    }


    return nil;
}

@end
```

It wouldn't be too hard to make a withLocale version, but I frankly don't quite understand how Locale is coded and have no need for it as of right now